# How can i split a row of data at an hour level?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to split each row of data at an hour level given an hour difference. 
I start with the following data :

[image]

and i would like to output this result :

[image]

Tally is the number of times an event occurs in between the two dates, New_date would be the start of each segment and new_tally a division of the original tally following the proportion of time for each segment.

I have tried executing the sqlfiddle in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821041/oracle-split-a-time-duration-row-by-one-hour-period), but i get the following error:

> ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Exact code from the fiddle:

```
    create table log_table
        ( dt1 date, dt2 date
        );

    insert into log_table values(sysdate,sysdate-5/24);

    select greatest(dt2, trunc(dt2+(level-1)/24, 'hh24')), least(dt1, trunc(dt2+(level)/24, 'hh24'))
    from log_table connect by level <= floor((dt1-dt2)*24)+1;
```

This might have to do with the fact that i am trying this in an Oracle 8i DB. I've also been trying to understand how hierarchical queries work but i find them really complicated.

Could someone give me an example and explain what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Nega.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried; or a link to the Fiddle you got an error on, which presumably includes your data set-up and the query?

Comment: This is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82625/29 .It is not my code though, it is the one in the question i linked.

Comment: I don't get the ORA-01436 from that Fiddle, so I'm a bit confused. I can imagine how you might get it from trying to adapt it, but it would help if you showed the actual code you're running. I can sort of see what you're dong; but why don't you want a new_date at 16:00? And why is the last new_tally 0.91719 instead of 0.575525 - assuming they should add up to 7?

Comment: Yes,sorry for the misscalculation. It should add up to 7, each entry should have the tally value proportionate to the minutes for that segment. I edited the question with the exact code.

Comment: Are you saying you get ORA-01436 from exactly that code in 8i? Might be a red-herring though. Still not sure why you don't have a 16:00 row; without it the gap from 15:00 to 16:23 is going to be the biggest period, is that correct?

Comment: There only needs to be a row/segment for each hour, be it 1 full hour or just a couple of minutes, so if the interval extends from hour 11 to 16 it would only be 6 entries. This way the new tally can be calculated on an hour basis.

Comment: It made more sense when I split the start and end of each period out, rather than merging them into a single `new_date`; that's what was confusing me, as it's sometimes the start of the split period and sometimes the end. (I was also confusing the tally with the number of rows expected for a while!). I got it out as six periods, anyway, and calculated the new split tally. Support for 8i may be an issue though. (Why are you still using such an ancient version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how happy 8i will be with this, but you can split the records up into hour (or partial hour) chunks with a hierarchical query like this:

```
select firstoccurrence, lastoccurrence, tally,
  greatest(firstoccurrence,
    trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + (level - 1) / 24) as new_start,
  least(lastoccurrence,
    trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + level / 24) as new_end
from t42
connect by firstoccurrence = prior firstoccurrence
and prior sys_guid() is not null
and trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + (level - 1) / 24
  <= trunc(lastoccurrence, 'HH24');
```

... where t42 is a table populated as in your first image. That gives:

```
FIRSTOCCURRENCE     LASTOCCURRENCE      TALLY NEW_START           NEW_END           
------------------- ------------------- ----- ------------------- -------------------
2014-12-04 11:33:16 2014-12-04 11:33:36     1 2014-12-04 11:33:16 2014-12-04 11:33:36
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 12:00:00
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 12:00:00 2014-12-30 13:00:00
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 13:00:00 2014-12-30 14:00:00
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 14:00:00 2014-12-30 15:00:00
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 15:00:00 2014-12-30 16:00:00
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 16:00:00 2014-12-30 16:23:08
```

You can then use that as a CTE, or as I don't think 8i knows about CTEs an inline view, and calculate the difference between each time and it's proportion against the original range, and divide the tally by that:

```
select firstoccurrence, lastoccurrence, tally, new_start, new_end,
  to_number(to_char(new_start, 'HH24')) as new_hour,
  tally / ((lastoccurrence - firstoccurrence) / (new_end - new_start)) as new_tally
from (
  select firstoccurrence, lastoccurrence, tally,
    greatest(firstoccurrence,
      trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + (level - 1) / 24) as new_start,
    least(lastoccurrence,
      trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + level / 24) as new_end
  from t42
  connect by firstoccurrence = prior firstoccurrence
  and prior sys_guid() is not null
  and trunc(firstoccurrence, 'HH24') + (level - 1) / 24
    <= trunc(lastoccurrence, 'HH24')
);

FIRSTOCCURRENCE     LASTOCCURRENCE      TALLY NEW_START           NEW_END             NEW_HOUR   NEW_TALLY
------------------- ------------------- ----- ------------------- ------------------- -------- -----------
2014-12-04 11:33:16 2014-12-04 11:33:36     1 2014-12-04 11:33:16 2014-12-04 11:33:36       11    1.000000
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 12:00:00       11     .453619
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 12:00:00 2014-12-30 13:00:00       12    1.492714
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 13:00:00 2014-12-30 14:00:00       13    1.492714
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 14:00:00 2014-12-30 15:00:00       14    1.492714
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 15:00:00 2014-12-30 16:00:00       15    1.492714
2014-12-30 11:41:46 2014-12-30 16:23:08     7 2014-12-30 16:00:00 2014-12-30 16:23:08       16     .575524
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2de4/2); but that's 11gR2 so doesn't mean it'll work in 8i. I don't have such an ancient version to test on unfortunately.

If your table has an ID column then use that for the `connect by prior` clause - I've had to use `firstoccurrence` and hope it's unique. You may also need to use `dbms_random.value` instead of `sys_guid()` - an non-deterministic function will do though.

Comment: Thanks Alex, im gona try it out.