# Oracle, split a time duration multiple rows by one hour period

Tags: sql, oracle

I understand this question was answered here:

[Oracle, split a time duration row by one hour period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821041/oracle-split-a-time-duration-row-by-one-hour-period)

but, what about if you have multiple time periods like this:
[image]

I have the following query:

```
select AdmitDate, PatientName, Room, greatest(start_time, trunc(start_time+(level-1)/24, 'hh24')) beginTime, least(end_time, trunc(start_time+(level)/24, 'hh24')) endTime
from Utilization
connect by level <= floor((trunc(end_time, 'hh')-trunc(start_time, 'hh'))*24)+1
```

but it returns the results below which appears to be incorrect.
[image]

If I have a single time row table it works great.

Is there a way I can group the results by PatientName or just each row calculated separatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really very close. Add a DISTINCT and an ORDER BY and I think you've got the results you were looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AdmitDate,
                PatientName,
                Room,
                greatest(start_time, trunc(start_time+(level-1)/24, 'hh24')) beginTime,
                least(end_time, trunc(start_time+(level)/24, 'hh24')) endTime
  from Utilization
  connect by level <= floor((trunc(end_time, 'hh')-trunc(start_time, 'hh'))*24)+1
  ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

This produces:

```
ADMITDATE               PATIENTNAME ROOM BEGINTIME              ENDTIME
2012-01-24 00:00:00     Patient1    RM1  2012-01-24 07:30:00    2012-01-24 08:00:00
2012-01-24 00:00:00     Patient1    RM1  2012-01-24 08:00:00    2012-01-24 08:32:00
2012-01-24 00:00:00     Patient2    RM1  2012-01-24 08:45:00    2012-01-24 09:00:00
2012-01-24 00:00:00     Patient2    RM1  2012-01-24 09:00:00    2012-01-24 09:13:00
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5edd7/3)